# Why this string matches the regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

Why this string matches the pattern ?

```
  pattern = """
    ^Page \d of \d$|
    ^Group \d Notes$|
    ^More word lists and tips at http://wwwmajortests.com/word-lists$|
    """
    re.match(pattern, "stackoverflow", re.VERBOSE)
```

According to me it should match strings like "Page 1 of 1" or  "Group 1 Notes".

Comment: because of the trailing `|` perhaps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your regular expression, there's trailing `|`:

```
# ^More word lists and tips at http://wwwmajortests.com/word-lists$|
#                                                                  ^
```

Empty pattern matches any string:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('abc|', 'abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fc63f3ff3d8>
>>> re.match('abc|', 'bbbb')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fc63f3ff440>
```

So, Remove the trailing `|`.

BTW, you don't need `^` becasue [`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) checks for a match only at the beginning of the string.

And, I recommend you to use raw strings(`r'....'`) to correctly escape backslahes.

---

**ADDITIONAL NOTE**

`\d` matches only a single digit. Use `\d+` if you also want to match multiple digits.